# Better PHP usort()

Tags: php, usort

I needed to merge and then sort two arrays with dissimilar data structures (can't be sorted in the MySQL query) but where both had a `created_on` field.

So I am using `usort()` with a custom function.

**In my controller**

```
usort(merged_array, 'sort_records');
```

**In my helper functions**

```
if(!function_exists('sort_records')){
  function sort_records($a,$b){
    if ( $a['created_at'] == $b['created_at'] )
      return 0;
    if ( $a['created_at'] < $b['created_at'] )
       return -1;
    return 1;
  } 
}
```

I would like to make this `sort_records()` function reusable. So I can use it with other arrays. Maybe something like..

```
function sort_records($a,$b,$index){
  if ( $a[$index] == $b[$index] )
     return 0;
  if ( $a[$index] < $b[$index] )
     return -1;
  return 1;
```

Is this possible with `usort()` since when you call the function it does not take parameters at all? Is there another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `usort` inside `sort_records` and use anonymous function, like so:

```
function sort_records(&$array,$index){
    return usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($index) {
        if ( $a[$index] == $b[$index] )
            return 0;
        if ( $a[$index] < $b[$index] )
            return -1;
        return 1;
    });
}
```

Then you can call it with whatever index you need

```
sort_records($array, 'created_at');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class

```
class SortRecord
{
    private $index;

    public function __construct($index)
    {
        $this->index = $index;
    }

    public function sort_records($a, $b)
    {
        if ( $a[$this->index] == $b[$this->index] )
            return 0;
        if ( $a[$this->index] < $b[$this->index] )
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

then you can pass it to `usort`.

```
$obj = new SortRecord('created_at');
usort($merged_array, array($obj, 'sort_records'));
```

Comment: I actually like this a lot but one of the other answers is better for my current application.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `use` keyword on your usort, but you'd have to declare the inner function as [anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) :

```
function better_usort($array, $index) {
    return usort($array, function($a, $b) use($index){
        if ($a[$index] == $b[$index])
            return 0;
        if ($a[$index] < $b[$index])
            return -1;
        return 1;
    });
}
```

And then you can call it with

```
better_usort($merged_array, 'created_at');
```